# MySQL: Trigger Before Update Not Working

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to get a trigger to run before an update is processed on a per record level of a table.

What I'm trying to do is when an update occurs on a record for the `qst_title` column, if the column `qst_perma_title` is NULL then the `qst_perma_title` column is updated with the value in the `qst_title` column and the `qst_title` column is updated as per the original update query.

I'm using the code below but no errors are shown and the column `qst_perma_title` isn't updated.

The current values are:

`qst_title` = 'Old Title'

`qst_perma_title`  = NULL

**query**

UPDATE TD_QUESTION SET `qst_title` = 'New Title Value' WHERE `qst_id` = 1;

**trigger**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_QST_UPD
BEFORE UPDATE ON TD_QUESTION
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF OLD.`qst_perma_title` IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.`qst_perma_title` = OLD.`qst_title`;
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Does `qst_title` updated with new title?

Comment: Your question asks when an update occurs on a record for the qst_title but your script doesn't.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gZSYsRQRtKhVojHzS2dJEs/0).

Comment: @Harshil, yes the column `qst_title` updates ok.

Comment: Are you sure your column is null for the row you are trying to update ? What happens if you remove the `IF OLD.qst_perma_title IS NULL THEN`

Comment: @ThomasG, yes the column in NULL, only one record in the table, I've removed the `IF NULL` bit and it still wont update the `qst_perma_title` column.

Comment: `qst_perma_title` is also in `TD_QUESTION` table, right?

Comment: I dont understand because your TRIGGER is correct

Comment: Working now, another developer had explicitly disabled triggers using `SET @disable_triggers = 1;`, reverted their change, all working perfect now. Thanks for all the help, thought I was going crazy.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_QST_UPD 
BEFORE UPDATE ON TD_QUESTION 
FOR EACH ROW 
    IF OLD.qst_perma_title IS NULL THEN 
    SET NEW.qst_perma_title = OLD.qst_title;
END IF;
```

First run this query and then try updating. I checked, it is working fine for me.

Comment: Can you explain what you changed any why?